Trying to fish ethernet
So I'm trying to fish a cable between first and second floor. There seems to be something in the way. Can't tell if it's a joist between the studs with debris on it or if it's actually brick or concrete. Not sure what's going on. Took a pic of where the stud meets the thing blocking the way down. Looked some stuff up and couldn't find anything. This is a rowhome. Any ideas what that is?


rent a fiberoptic camera

Ordered an endoscope to get a better look at what's going on back there. Figured I'd post to see if anyone had any idea what it was.

Are you trying to fish around that framing member (assumed to be a top plate, although wondering why stud spacing looks so big), or through it?

Ideally around it, but it doesn't seem doable. Tried getting around it with a fishing tool. I just couldn't tell if it was wood. There's a lot of debris on it so it's difficult to tell. I'd be willing to go through it if I could verify what it is before I open up the wall further.

How is it not the floor that is in the way?
Note that the brick wall was previously plastered and finished
for that the floor must extend to the plaster surface.

Really hard to see in the photo.  It almost looks like carpet padding.

The classic solution would indeed be to find the blockage, open the wall at that point, and drill through it, then patch the hole.
As an alternative, there are cable fishing rods which have a drill bit at one end, letting one drill a passage from some distance above or below through a relatively small entry hole, no there are some obvious risks in operating a drill where you can't see what it's drilling into. If you web search "cable fishing drill" you will find these, and probably an article or two on using them.
As a perhaps simpler solution: in a typical two-story residence, almost every wall can be accessed for wiring from either the basement or the attic. It may be simpler to find a cable or piping raceway between basement and attic, run the cable through that, and then only have to deal with one floor's walls at a time. Blocking me still be an obstacle, but this will often avoid having to open finished walls.
